# How do you draw smooth curves given integer amplitude points?

Tags: java, android, math

I'm trying to draw a sinus wave-form (think Siri) that picks up and is immediately influenced by a user's voice. If I could accomplish exactly [this](https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCSiriWaveformView) in Android with as much fluidity on a device such as the S4, I will be extremely satisfied, so *any* helpful information is greatly appreciated.

Right now, I understand how to use the `MediaRecorder` to grab the max amplitude at a "tick" ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude%28%29)), and I can store several of these integer values in an array as the `MediaRecorder` is recording and picking up audio, but I have no idea how I can transform this array of integers into something like the Github project that I posted above. I'd also appreciate if someone could suggest how large this array should be, since I want to dump old data as quickly as possible to make the animation fast and use as little memory as possible.

Answer (score 0):

EMy aproach would be as follows: You could store, say, the last 5 values (In your example, it shows about 5-6 lines at a time).

Then, for each value in these 5 values:
Take the max amplitude value you can get for reference, and use it for calculate a percentage of the current value. Use that percentage along with the sin(x)[Math.sin](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)) function to smooth the curvy line:

example:

MAX_AMPL:1200
CURR_VALUE: 240  -->20% of MAX_AMPL

Use android drawing primitives [Drwaing on android](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) to draw  f(x)=(CURR_VALUE/MAX_VALUE) Math.Sin (x)
If you draw the function between 0 and 2Pi i think you will get the same number of waves as in your example.

The more recent the value (position in value ArrayList), the more wider the line for vanishing efect.
Last, draw your graphs from the oldest to the newer.